I2C master - the necessary information does not latch in one of the states of the state machine
I am creating an I2C master.  I built a finite state machine from 3 always blocks. After writing/reading data via the interface, the WACK2 state occurs, in which the write by slave is confirmed by setting an ACK, or the read ends when the NACK by master is set. In my case, I am recording, and the last bit of the transmitted data is set at the moment of transition to the WACK2 state, respectively, the slave cannot set anything to the sda line, because the line direction has not changed yet. And eventually a data bit is snapped into the rx bus, not a response from the slave.
I guess the problem is that my states change according to the same clk that the data in the previous state is exposed to. I tried to make the states and latching of new data occur by posedge and negedge, respectively, and vice versa, but this did not give any results.
I need the information received from the slave to be latched into the rx bus in the WACK2 state, and not the bit of data being transmitted
I2C MASTER code:
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module I2C_master(
    input        clk_i, rst_i,                   
    input        start_cmd, stop_cmd,  
    input        rnw_i,     //     read/ not write        
    input        wack2_master_i,
    input  [6:0] addr_i, 
    input  [7:0] din_i,     // data_in
    output [7:0] dout_o,            
    output       i2c_scl_o,
    inout        i2c_sda_io,
    output       ack_o,
    output       ready_o    //data ready             
    );

   
    localparam ACK  = 1'b0;
    localparam NACK = 1'b1;
    logic sda_r, scl_r;    //sda, scl registers
    logic sda_dir;         //direction for sda line
    logic ready_r;
  
    assign i2c_sda_io = sda_dir? sda_r : 1'bz;
    assign i2c_scl_o = scl_r;

    enum logic[3:0]
  {
     IDLE    = 4'd0,
     START   = 4'd1,       
     ADDR    = 4'd2,
     RW      = 4'd3,
     WACK    = 4'd4,
     READ    = 4'd5,
     WRITE   = 4'd6,
     WACK2   = 4'd7,
     HOLD    = 4'd8,
     STOP    = 4'd9  
  }state, new_state;

    logic [2:0] cnt;
    logic [8:0] rx;
    
    assign scl_r = ((state == START) || (state == STOP) || (state == IDLE))? 1 : clk_i;
 
    //3-FSM start
    always_ff@(posedge clk_i) 
        if(rst_i) begin
           state <= IDLE;
           rx    <= '0;
        end
        else state <= new_state;  

    always_comb begin
        new_state = state; 
        case(state)
          IDLE : if(start_cmd)                      new_state = START;
          START:                                    new_state = ADDR;
          ADDR : if(cnt == 0)                       new_state = RW;
          RW   :                                    new_state = WACK;
          WACK : if(i2c_sda_io == ACK)begin 
                    if(rnw_i)                         new_state = READ; 
                    else                            new_state = WRITE;
                 end                                     
          READ : if(cnt == 0)                       new_state = WACK2;
          WRITE: if(cnt == 0)                       new_state = WACK2;
          WACK2:                                    new_state = HOLD;
          HOLD : if(rnw_i) begin
                  if (rx[0] == NACK)begin
                    if(stop_cmd)                    new_state = STOP;
                  end              
                  else                              new_state = READ; 
                 end
                 else    begin
                  if (rx[0] == ACK) begin
                    if (stop_cmd)                   new_state = STOP;
                    else                            new_state = WRITE;
                  end
                  else                              new_state = STOP;
                 end

          STOP :                                    new_state = IDLE;
        endcase
    end

    always_ff@(posedge clk_i) begin
        case(state)
          IDLE : 
               begin
                ready_r     <= 1'b0;
                sda_dir     <= 1'b1;
                sda_r       <= 1'b1;
               end
          START: 
               begin
                 sda_dir    <= 1'b1;
                 sda_r      <= 1'b0;
                 cnt        <= 3'd6;
               end
          ADDR : 
               begin
                 sda_dir    <= 1'b1;
                 sda_r      <= addr_i[cnt];
                 cnt        <= cnt - 1;
               end
          RW   :
               begin
                 sda_dir    <= 1'b1;
                 sda_r      <= rnw_i;
               end
          WACK : 
               begin
                 sda_dir    <= 1'b0;
                 cnt        <= 3'd7; 
               end
                 
          READ :
               begin
                 ready_r    <= 1'b0;
                 sda_dir    <= 1'b0;
                 rx         <= {rx[8:1], i2c_sda_io};
                 cnt        <= cnt - 1;
               end
          WRITE:
               begin
                ready_r     <= 1'b0;
                sda_dir     <= 1'b1;
                sda_r       <= din_i[cnt];
                cnt         <= cnt - 1;
               end
          WACK2: 
               begin
                 if(rnw_i) begin
                   sda_dir <= 1'b1;
                   sda_r   <= wack2_master_i;
                   rx      <= wack2_master_i;
                   ready_r <= 1'b1;
                 end
                 else begin
                   sda_dir = 1'b0;
                   rx      = {rx[8:1], i2c_sda_io};
                   ready_r = 1'b1;
                 end
               end 
          HOLD : cnt        <= 3'd7;            
          STOP : 
               begin
                sda_dir     <= 1'b1;
                sda_r       <= 1'b1;
               end
        endcase
    end
   //3-FSM end

   assign dout_o  = rx[8:1];
   assign ack_o   = rx[0];  
   assign ready_o = ready_r;
endmodule

TESTBENCH:
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module tb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk_i;
    reg rst_i;
    reg start_cmd;
    reg stop_cmd;
    reg rnw;
    reg [6:0] addr_i;
    reg [7:0] din_i;
    reg wack2_master;
    // Outputs
    wire [7:0] dout_o;
    wire i2c_scl_o;
    wire ack_o;
    wire ready_o;

    // Bidirectional
    wire i2c_sda_io;
    reg i2c_sda_io_reg;
    assign i2c_sda_io = i2c_sda_io_reg;

    // Instantiate the I2C_master
    I2C_master uut (
        .clk_i(clk_i),
        .rst_i(rst_i),
        .start_cmd(start_cmd),
        .stop_cmd(stop_cmd),
        .rnw_i(rnw),
        .addr_i(addr_i),
        .din_i(din_i),
        .dout_o(dout_o),
        .i2c_scl_o(i2c_scl_o),
        .i2c_sda_io(i2c_sda_io),
        .ack_o(ack_o),
        .ready_o(ready_o),
        .wack2_master_i(wack2_master)
    );

    // Clock generation
    initial begin
        clk_i = 0;
        forever #5 clk_i = ~clk_i; // 100MHz clock
    end

    // Test sequence
    initial begin
        // Initialize inputs
        rst_i = 1;
        start_cmd = 0;
        stop_cmd = 0;
        rnw = 0;
        addr_i = 7'b1010000; // Example I2C address
        din_i = 8'h00;
        i2c_sda_io_reg = 1'bz; // High impedance

        // Reset the device
        #10 rst_i = 0;

        // Test 1: Write operation
        #10 start_cmd = 1;
        #10 start_cmd = 0;
        rnw = 0; // Write operation
        din_i = 8'h55; // Example data to write
        #95 i2c_sda_io_reg = 1'b0;
        #5  i2c_sda_io_reg = 1'bz;
        #85 i2c_sda_io_reg = 1'b0;
        #100 stop_cmd = 1;
        #10 stop_cmd = 0;

        i2c_sda_io_reg = 1'bz;
       
       
        // Finish simulation
        #100 $finish;
    end

endmodule



There are multiple problems with your Verilog code.
The code has compile errors on 4 different simulators on the EDA Playground site.  Copy your code there to see the error messages.  You should fix those errors.  For example, remove rx from the 1st always_ff block and reset it in the 2nd always_ff block:
always_ff@(posedge clk_i) begin
    if(rst_i)
       rx    <= '0;
    else
    case(state)

You are not driving the wack2_master  testbench signal to a known value, and it is propagating x's into the design.
You should drive the uut inputs synchronous to the clock, not using # delays.  You may have simulation race conditions.
